# How do I embed a Smalltalk code editor into my application?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I'm building a blog entry viewer and editor application in my Pharo image, and the entry content is formatted as Smalltalk code (the Seaside markup API is really nice).  I'm pretty new to Smalltalk, so I was using [this blog post](http://magaloma.blogspot.com/2011/01/pharo-gui-with-polymorph.html) as an example.

I currently have this for my `BlogEditor>>open` method:

```
open
| builder content |

builder := UITheme builder.
content := builder newColumn: {
    builder newRow: {
        builder newListFor: self
        list: #entries 
        selected: #entrySelectedIndex
        changeSelected: #entrySelectedIndex:
        help: 'Blog entries'.
    }.
    builder newRow: {
        editor := builder
            newTextEditorFor: self
            getText: #readSelectedEntry
            setText: #changeSelectedEntry:.
        editor minHeight: 400 } }.

(content openInWindowLabeled: 'Entries') extent: 800@700
```

I don't know what to put in place of `editor := builder newTextEditorFor:`.  I saw the class `SmalltalkEditor`, but I don't know how to put one on my UI.

Answer (score 1):

Put the line

```
self halt.
```

below

```
builder := UITheme builder.
```

Run the code. When it halts, debug and select the builder. Browse it to see what else you can add.

You do know a Text in Pharo has formatting? Just browse Text.

Answer (score 1):

What can be used is a PluggableTextMorph, which refers to a TextMorphForEditView, which in turn gives you a SmalltalkEditor.

PluggableTextMorph is a ScrollPane

You can also look in the TextMorph which could come handy.

The UITheme builder hides all of the nasty details inside but it will bring you back to the classes mentioned above.

Good luck.